# What does 弁当箱をしまった mean?

Tags: verbs, phrases

I was playing a Japanese video game when I came across this line:

> 私は立ち上がり、お弁当箱をしまった

I was just wondering, can I translate お弁当箱をしまった as "carry the bentou box"?

Comment: You're probably misreading the text. It's しま**っ**た (仕舞った), not しま**し**た. Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/45197/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23757/9831

Answer (score 4):

It's not する, it's しまう.
しまう + た → しまった

しまう = pack up